# P212 Smart array not configured

Tags: hp-smart-array

First of all thanks for all your help.

I have purchased a used HP DL380 G7 for my home.

This is my first server installation and all going well for the raid configuration P410I and ESXI installation.

I have purchased a D2600 with a P212 raid with 512MB no battery. I have also taken the cable required to connect both together (original HP)

Now I am not able to configure raid.

The card is in HBA mode and when I try to configure raid with the ESXI HPSSACLI I have a failed message: Controller not configured.

I try to activate raid and I have another error.

What I'm missing? I can send picture of error message if needed.

**Update 1**

[Detail of the P212](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qATaU.png)

[Error to disable HBAmode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deieF.png)

and

[Controller not configured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmnkW.png)

**Update 2**

When I reboot the server and presse F8 and before entering the CLI mode, I have this message appear: raid controller is disabled via NVRAM. I think this message is not good

Answer (score 1):

The HP Smart Array P212 controller is really meant for connecting external tape drives to the server. If it's acting like it is in HBA mode, then you'll see each of the disks inside of the D2600 as separate drives in ESXi.

Comment: So if I understand your answer, the P212 can do raid only with the internal port? It is not mentionned in the P212 brochure. It only tell me this:

The SA-P212 Controller supports the HP D2600 Disk Enclosure, HP D2700 Disk Enclosure, and the HP 600 Modular Disk System. 6Gb/s SAS technology delivers high performance and data bandwidth and contains full compatibility with 3Gb/s SATA technology.

Comment: You should post your errors.

Comment: When I try to disable the HBA mode, I have : the controller is not configured, I have boot with ACU and I do not have any option to modify. I have try disconnected the memory and same error but the P212 now are not able to connect on the SAS due to not having memory. I am not able to assign read/write cache due to HBA mode ON. I have take a look and it is not require to have battery as it is only use for raid 6 and 6+ with license. I do not have licence

Comment: The controller will remain in RAID mode. No reboot is requried for the change to take effect.
Error: This operation is not supported with the current configuration. Use the
       "show" command on devices to show additional details about the
       configuration.
Reason: Not supported

Answer (score 0):

Since changing the state of the HBA Mode setting is a pretty fundamental change to the functioning of the card, it might not be possible to do it with the OS (ESXi in this case) running.

When the server is running its self-tests at boot, there should be a message about the Smart Array controller. The message should indicate a key combination to press to access its configuration menu. (On some HP Proliant DL380 generations, this message may be covered up by a giant HP logo screen: if this is the case, pressing Esc should clear the logo and make the boot messages visible.)

Comment: Hi telcoM, thanks for your reply, I have try to start with the CLI version of the F8 (raid utility) and it talk about NVRAM. I tell this message: Raid controller is disabled via NVRAM. I think the raid controller is just not working and/or broken. It is possible to do Something with this message?

Comment: Check the main BIOS settings of the server. If there is anything that looks like enabling/disabling add-on card BIOS extensions and/or add-on card boot, that might be it.

Comment: Hi telcoM, Already take a look at bios, the card is already in the boot section in second position, after the on board P410i. When i am in the ESXI, I can see all HDD and I can use it, I just can't make raid. I know I can do without, but I need raid 5 with spare to obtain logical drive with different capacity and not multiple HDD with maximum TB from what the physical drive give me. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Download the [HP Offline Smart Storage Administrator](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_024fe3a9a125415c80dc674685) DVD image and boot the system with it. You'll be able to configure your devices using this tool.

Comment: Hi ewwhite, already try, the HPE SSA offline, it is not available for Legacy but just UEFI, The Gen7 does not have UEFI. So because of this I have use the older version HP ACU, the tool does not allow me to modify anything. just to let poeple know I already update to last firmware for all my server including the P212 with the SPP. Thanks for your help!